# The package python-samba needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it

Tags: 16.04, package-management

Getting the error message:

```
E: The package python-samba needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it.
```

Bit of a catch-22, if I can't install, I can't re-install either.

If I run `sudo apt-get -f install`

```
Reading package lists... Done 
Building dependency tree        
Reading state information... Done 
The following additional packages will be installed: python-samba 
The following packages will be upgraded: python-samba 1 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 24 not upgraded. 4 not fully installed or removed. 
Need to get 0 B/1,062 kB of archives. 
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used. 
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y 
(Reading database ... 245710 files and directories currently installed.) 
Preparing to unpack .../python-samba_2%3a4.3.11+dfsg-ubuntu0.16.04.7_amd64.deb ...   
File "/usr/bin/pyclean", line 63
 except (IOError, OSError), e: SyntaxError: invalid syntax dpkg: warning: subprocess old pre-removal script returned error exit status 1 dpkg: trying script from the new package instead ...   
File "/usr/bin/pyclean", line 63
 except (IOError, OSError), e: SyntaxError: invalid syntax dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/python-samba_2%3a4.3.11+dfsg-0ubuntu0.16.04.7_amd64.deb
(--unpack):  subprocess new pre-removal script returned error exit
status 1 
Traceback (most recent call last):   
File "/usr/bin/pycompile", line 35, in <module> from debpython.version import SUPPORTED, debsorted, vrepr,     
File "/usr/share/python/debpython/version.py", line 24, in <module>
from ConfigParser import SafeConfigParser ImportError: No module named 'ConfigParser' dpkg: error while cleaning up:  
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1   
Errors were encountered while processing:  
  /var/cache/apt/archives/python-samba_2%3a4.3.11+dfsg-0ubuntu0.16.04.7_amd64.deb
  E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: I have it `python-samba/xenial-updates,xenial-security,now 2:4.3.11+dfsg-0ubuntu0.16.04.7 amd64 [installed,automatic]` in mine. What exactly are you doing?

Comment: Run this `apt search python-samba` and tell me what it outputs!

Comment: Whats the output of `sudo apt update` ?

Comment: I ran _apt search python-samba_ and got back: Sorting... Done
Full Text Search... Done
python-samba/now 2:4.3.11+dfsg-0ubuntu0.16.04.6 amd64 [installed,local]
  Python bindings for Samba

Comment: I ran _sudo apt update_ and got back a typical update (too long to post here) but here are the last few lines:
E: The repository 'http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian smp Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.

Answer (score 1):

My problem came about when I switched the default version of Python from Python2.7 to Python3.  When I switched back, the dependency issues were gone.

Comment: You have learned a valuable lesson: DO NOT CHANGE THE SYSTEM DEFAULT VERSION OF PYTHON. Elements of your system depend upon it, and changing Python breaks your system.